# Get all links of website using Selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium webdriver (java), I want to get all links of a given website, all pages. How can I do this?

I am being able to do for a particular web page of the website but, not the full website. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to do by navigating to only one of the page in the web site.

What you can do is for each page you visit you can retrieve the web links separately.

Then combine all these list together into one list and print it as shown below.

```
// Get all the available Links in Web Page A
    List<WebElement> linksA = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

// Get all the available Links in Web Page B
    List<WebElement> linksB = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

// Combine the two list into one list
    List<String> combineList = Stream.concat(linksA.stream(), linksB.stream()).toList();

// Iterating through all the Links and printing link
    
    for (WebElement link : combineList) {
        System.out.println(link.getText());
        System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
    }
```

Another solution is when visiting each web page you can use the same variable to add the URLs, so we do not need to combine each list.

Comment: you could use a HashMap so that each entry is a unique URL key.  Most link crawlers or 404 checkers will use a recursive loop, which is not really possible using Selenium so this answer is going to be the way to go.  You might need to track visited in another array.  (things get complicated without recursion...)